# Download to external storage using downloadManager doesn't work properly on Galaxy S7

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-external-storage

Downloading to internal storage works.

However, when I try to download to the external sdcard, then status doesn't update until after 2~3 minutes. (Meaning I get 0 bytes downloaded from cursor.getLong(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));).
It eventually downloads after 2~3 minutes.

The notification status also says 0%

[image]

```
private void addToDownloadManager(String sourcePath, String destFolder, String deskFileName, DownloadManager downloadManager) {
    try {
        if(sourcePath == null || sourcePath.equals(""))
            return;
        try {
            File folder = new File(destFolder);
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }

        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(sourcePath);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);

        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
        request.setTitle("title");
        request.setDescription("description");
        File destination = new File(destFolder, deskFileName);
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destination));
        downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

private Timer mDownloadStatusTimer;

public void downloadStatusTimerSchedule() {
    if (mDownloadStatusTimer != null)
        downloadStatusTimerCancel();
    try {
        mDownloadStatusTimer = new Timer("DownloadStatusTimer");
        DownloadStatusTimer timer = new DownloadStatusTimer();
        mDownloadStatusTimer.schedule(timer, 500, 500); // 0.5 second
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void downloadStatusTimerCancel() {
    if (mDownloadStatusTimer != null) {
        mDownloadStatusTimer.cancel();
        mDownloadStatusTimer.purge();
        mDownloadStatusTimer = null;
    }
}

private long bytes_downloaded = 0;
private long bytes_total = 0;

public class DownloadStatusTimer extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mDownloadManager != null) {
            DownloadManager.Query myDownloadQuery = new DownloadManager.Query();

            Cursor cursor = mDownloadManager.query(myDownloadQuery);

            bytes_downloaded = 0;
            bytes_total = 0;

            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    try {
                        // Get downloaded size/total size
                        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL ||
                                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED) {
                            // do nothing
                        } else {
                            bytes_downloaded += cursor.getLong(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                            bytes_total += cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        try {
                            // Get downloaded size/total size
                            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL ||
                                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED) {
                                // do nothing
                            } else {
                                bytes_downloaded += cursor.getLong(cursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                                bytes_total += cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }

            Log.e("test", "Download size: " + bytes_downloaded + " / " + bytes_total);
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        tv_download_status.setText("Download size: " + bytes_downloaded + " / " + bytes_total);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tested Note 4 and Galaxy S5 and they seems to be fine.

Could it be Android 6.0 thing? or S7? 
Is it a bug? Or is there anything I am doing wrong here?

If you want to test it yourself, here's the project with source code:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BygTefPD845LTkp5QU1mOHRkMDQ

Here's APK to test:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By...Ec1ZHk5ZWRkWWc

[image]

[Edit]

My destination location is: /storage/806E-1A11/Android/data/com.joshua.externalsddownloadtest/files/download/video.mp4

Source is: http://downloads.4ksamples.com/downloads/[2160p]%204K-HD.Club-2013-Taipei%20101%20Fireworks%20Trailer%20(4ksamples.com).mp4

(I got the URL from the Mp4 Sample website)

```
        File[] files = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(MainActivity.this, null);
    destFolder = null;
    for(int i=0; i< files.length; i++) {
        if (!files[i].getAbsolutePath().equals(MainActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath())) {
            destFolder = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
            break;
        }
    }
    boolean bDownloadToExternal = false;
    if(destFolder == null) {
        tv_download_destination.setText("No external storage found");
    } else {
        destFolder += "/download/";
        tv_download_destination.setText("Destination location: " + destFolder + fileName);
        bDownloadToExternal = true;
    }
```

Comment: "File destination = new File(destFolder, deskFileName);" -- what **exactly** is the value of `destination`?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I added "destination" path

Comment: `DownloadManager` maybe does not have access to arbitrary spots on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+. Ordinary apps don't.

Comment: It eventually downloads. First 2~3 minutes it just remains 0%.

Comment: DownloadManager does have the access to the removable storage. It also eventually downloads to the folder so write permission is not the issue. Maybe it is taking time to allocate the space in the removable storage? Because larger the file you're trying to download, longer it takes it seems.

Comment: You are using timer and timertask to show download status it is ok but as i remember timertask is discouraged for such uses by android developers but i cant find the original document so i found this post. it may be interesting for you. i recommend to use asynctask and publishprogress instead. http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

Answer (score 1):

I think its about new permission system at android 6.
You should ask permissions in runtime like:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != getPackageManager().PERMISSION_GRANTED){
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, YOUR_CONST_REQUEST_CODE);
           }
  }
```

And implement listener

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case YOUR_CONST_REQUEST_CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// invoke your download method

                    } else {
// if permissions was not granted
                    }

                } 
            }
    }
```

Other way you can set targetSdkVersion less then 23 in gradle file.

More about new permission system you can read here [Android.com](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: I should have mentioned, I already tried requestPermissions() & targetSdkVersion less than 23. It just 'freezes' for 2~3 minutes, but the download 'eventually' works. Nothing to do with the permission.